# How to restart a Jar file on init.d?

Tags: java, linux, centos

I am using CentOS 6.3 64bit.

I am using starting my server as a service.

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 2345 90 10
#description: URL Server
# processname: urlovedserver
start(){
java -jar /root/BookkServer-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
}
# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
   start
   ;;
  *)
   echo "Usage: $0 {start}"
   exit 1
esac
```

What should I add to the script so that it responds to "service urlovedserver restart"? I can't get how to stop a java service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `PID` in file. When you want you can read `PID-file` for kill java process.

```
start(){
    #run your process in background
    java -jar /root/BookkServer-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar &
    # write PID
    echo $! > program.pid  
}
```

Now you can kill process:

```
kill -9 `cat program.pid` #kill java process
```

Comment: Instead of using kill -9 PID. I decided to use pkill(or killall...).

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to get the pid of the executed command (use the `$!` shell variable) save it in a file and then add a stop command in your shell script that just kills the java process that it reads from the previous file. Something like

```
kill -9 `cat /var/run/myjavaservice.pid`.
```

Then restart will be just stop()  and start()